# Why successive recvfrom() call is blocking in case of UDP socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, io

In simple client-server program, Client is sending 12 bytes of data. I am using recvfrom(), requesting 2 and 10 bytes in successive calls. In case of first call recvfrom() is returning 2 bytes. But second call is blocking. Why it is so ? I think it wont happen with TCP sockets, where successive read calls returns the available bytes(10 here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recvfrom) has the following pertinent information (bold added):

> For message-based sockets, such as SOCK_RAW, SOCK_DGRAM, and SOCK_SEQPACKET, the entire message shall be read in a single operation. If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, and MSG_PEEK is not set in the flags argument, **the excess bytes shall be discarded**.

You need to read it in a single call.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about the third (`len`) parameter of recvfrom function.

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int s, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                 struct sockaddr *from, socklen_t *fromlen);
```

The latter indicate how big the buffer (`void *buf`) is, not how many bytes you want to extract from the packet.

In a `UDP` type socket you have to read the whole packet the other peer sent to you (`UDP` ensure it will arrive not fragmented) and avoid multiple read of the data sent just like `TCP` mode.

In your case, if your buffer is 2 bytes, the other 10 will be discarded (look at `recvfrom` man page)